# Calling an endpoint Google APIs Objective-C Client Library for REST from iOS Swift project

Tags: swift, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

This is my first swift and google app engine experience.

I created a simple java backend, made a discovery document, used service generator (the new REST service generator) to create the client libraries, added all google-specfic client libraries.

I cannot get passed a compiler error in the query ..

here is the code:

```
    let service: GTLRHelloworldService =  GTLRHelloworldService()
//no compiler problem with this line.
//my GTLRHellowworldService is included through the bridging headers
        service.isRetryEnabled = true
        set myquery: GTLRHelloworldQuery_GreetingsEstablishHandShake = GTLRHelloworldQuery_GreetingsEstablishHandShake.query()

        service.executeQuery(myquery) { (ticket:GTLRServiceTicket, resp:GTLRHelloworld_HelloGreeting, error: NSError) in
                    nameLabel.text = resp?.message
                }
```

The error is in the last line:

Cannot convert value of type '(GTLRServiceTicket, GTLRHelloworld_HelloGreeting, NSError) -> ()' to expected argument type 'GTLRServiceCompletionHandler?'

For your information the GreetingsEstablishHandShake definition in the header file created by the servicegnerator is:

```
/**
 *  GTLRHelloworldQuery_GreetingsEstablishHandShake
 *
 *  Method: helloworld.greetings.establishHandShake
 *
 *  Authorization scope(s):
 *    @c kGTLRAuthScopeHelloworldUserinfoEmail
 */
@interface GTLRHelloworldQuery_GreetingsEstablishHandShake : GTLRHelloworldQuery
// Previous library name was
//   +[GTLQueryHelloworld queryForGreetingsEstablishHandShake]

/**
 *  Fetches a @c GTLRHelloworld_HelloGreeting.
 *
 *  @returns GTLRHelloworldQuery_GreetingsEstablishHandShake
 */
+ (instancetype)query;

@end
```

and the HelloGreeting object in the header file is:

```
@interface GTLRHelloworld_HelloGreeting : GTLRObject

@property(nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSString *message;

@end
```